# Font-awesome fonts proving problematic with IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-awesome, webfonts

We are using Font-Awesome 4.0.2, and have been doing so for about 18 months. Just recently, with IE 11.0.9600 17843, we have noticed intermittent rendering issues. We can CTRL-F5, and the fonts appear, then go off the page and return and find some fonts absent. When you hover over them they reappear.

On some instance of the same IE11 browser(64bit not 32bit) it works fine. We have checked the security settings ie fonts can be downloaded.

There is no issue with Mozilla or Chrome.

Weirdly the problem exist with the live site and not the QA site. Both are on the internet.

I have have researched this, and the intermittent nature is the key, and it may point to a bug in a recent IE11 update, since this did work with IE11.

Advice appreciated...

Should we update to the newest Font-Awesome ie 4.3, or is this newer version just contain more fonts?

Thanks in advance.